# Thonny IDE throws ImportError during startup

Tags: python, importerror, thonny

I have been using the `Thonny` IDE for some time. It used to work perfectly. Then, some days ago, I had to format my laptop. After formatting, opening `Thonny` shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
 File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
 File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\runpy.py",
line 203, in run_module
  mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name)
 File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\runpy.py",
line 144, in _get_module_details
  return _get_ module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
 File "C\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\runpy.py",
line 111, in_get_module_details
   _import_(pkg_name)
 File
"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\th
onny\_init_.py", line 155, in <module>
  THONNY_USER_DIR =_compute_thonny_user_dir()
 File
"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\th
onny\_init_.py", line 77, in_compute_thonny_user_dir
  elif is_portable():
 File
"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\th
onny\_init_.py", line 133, in is_portable
  from ctypes import windll
 File
"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\ctypes\_init_.p
y", line 7, in <module>
from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: The parameter is
incorrect.
```

Versions:

- OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- Python: Python 3.8.10(32bit)
- Thonny:4.0.1

Any help in this matter is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried update it: pip install -U thonnyapp

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same error installing Thonny (thonny-py38-4.1.1) on a freshly installed win 7 prof 64 SP1.
After installing all available Windows-7-updates (I found found some 3rd-party update-tool for my german version), thonny worked fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).